# Can't find SQLS connection settings on my system, 32-bit app, wrong registry?

Tags: windows-registry, 64-bit, 32-bit

I hope this is the right forum.

A customer is moving their SQLS instance they use with a 3rd party application, AE. The settings can only be updated within the app, which is a bit annoying. They asked me if there was any easy way to verify that a particular machine had been updated. "Sure", I thought, "that should be easy."

I set up a new SQLS instance on my machine with the database name "xyzzy_123", then connected the app to it and saved the resulting settings under the connection name "uniquexyzzy". I first looked in the local file system because the app sort of works that way in most cases. I did searches through ever-expanding parts of my system, and it just doesn't find that string. It DID find xyzzy in a completely unrelated java file, so maybe that suggests at least search is working... sorta?

So it has to be the registry! I ran regedit, and nope, nothing. So, my real question...

The app in question is 32-bit. As I understand it, Win11's regedit.exe will look for keys from both 32 and 64 bit programs. Is that correct?

Looking in the SysWOW64 directory, I see both regedit.exe and regedt32.exe, but launching the latter results in what appears to be the same program, the About says version 22H2. Is that expected?

Anything I might be missing here in regedit terms?

Comment: or its encrypted or embedded in a non-text file. connection strings commonly contain privileged information like credentials, so its usually considered bad form to just place them in a text-based config file. if you have a compiled exe/dll, you could try using the strings.exe tool from Sysinternals to look inside it for the connection string. if it is in a config file, its most likely to be in the same directory as the app, or in your users %appdata% directory. Traditionally, a system level connection string would be a DSN, so you may want to check control panel > data sources as admin

Comment: @FrankThomas - thanks for the tips. I'll try strings. I did look in the sources control, I forgot to mention that.